# How to enable TCP with OpenVPN

Tags: tcp, openvpn

I am installing OpenVPN(version 2.3.6) in Windows 7,the server IP address is:192.168.1.222(firewall closed),the client IP is:192.168.1.240(firewall closed).The client conect to server directly success(Local Area Network).When connect to server through public network,the log is:

```
Wed Feb 17 10:40:58 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1455676858,WAIT,,,
Wed Feb 17 10:41:59 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Feb 17 10:41:59 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed Feb 17 10:41:59 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed Feb 17 10:41:59 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1455676919,RECONNECTING,tls-error
```

when I using NMAP to scan public IP,the OpenVPN port(1194) is closed.And I use command to find port status:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -an |find /i "1194"
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1194           *:*
```

Just only UDP.So my question is:How to enable OpenVPN's TCP port? So I could connect to OpenVPN through public network(Wide Area Network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your server.conf file and there should be entries to control this setting. If you're running on Windows, it should be in C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\ or something similar.
Look for something similar to this:

/# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
/# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
/# on the same machine, use a different port
/# number for each one.  You will need to
/# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

/# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

I'd recommend bookmarking this link and let it be your OpenVPN bible.
https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

Good luck!

Comment: In addition to this answer you should be aware of the problems that may arise by using a tcp based solution. If you try to access tcp-based components within the vpn (such as http, ftp, ...), you may experience significant increases in response time (For a better explanation see [here](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html)). This problem may especially become noticable when you access your vpn via an unreliable connection like the internet.